# RF transceiver WITHOUT built-in modulation

Tags: rf, communication, components, modulation

I'm trying to find an RF front-end module for a simple data transmission system of 500 bps.

Since I'm testing different encryptions, I want to modulate the signal, encrypt it, and then transmit it. All the transceivers I've found over the past week have some type of modulation built in. I want something that will just step up the frequency, bandpass it, and transmit it as is, without any modulation (because I modulated it earlier).

the only one I've found that doesnt list a built in modulation is nRF2460 (mono- audio streamer) will that do the trick?

Is there a specific name/type of transceiver that I should be searching for (like streamers)?

I'm a beginner and i'd like to find a prebuilt transceiver module instead of having to design all the filters,mixers, and antennas etc. that are necessary.

Comment: Are you _sure_ you want to modulate before encrypting? That inherently changes the modulation and thus the radio characteristics of the signal!

Comment: yes. i have a working baseband module (using arduino DUE's). I'm trying to take it to the broadband level (RF).

Comment: I'm at the point where I realize i have to be missing some information about why i cant send a modulated analog signal into a transceiver and it will boost, bandpass,and transmit it without modulating it again. what am i missing?!

Comment: I think we have a terminology issue here: The process of converting from baseband to RF **is** modulation! On the other hand, if what you really have is a modulated IF signal, then you just need a frequency translator, and those are generally not available as complete modules, but rather assembled from readily-available building blocks (mixers, filters, amplifiers) for each application.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Modulation is not upconversion. You can modulate 1kHz signal, which isn't RF. Modulation is changing a signal in a way that it converys information, regardless of frequency.

Comment: @Sam - you can in fact find systems which will do precisely what you want.  However, it's worth asking why you need to care what the ultimate form of transmission is.  If the signal out of the receiver is a sufficiently faithful reproduction of the signal into the transmitter, does it really matter if it's re-modulated in between?  Example reasons why you might care would be regulatory compliance, power or spectral efficiency, interoperability with other equipment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For a small, single-ended bandwidth a Single Side Band Suppressed Carrier (SSB) transmitter basically accomplishes what you want, mixing (linearly translating) an audio signal up to RF.  The receiver will do the complementary task, though any tuning error between that and the transmitter will result in a spectral shift.  This is sometimes used for data communication, for example feeding an audio FSK modem's output into the transmitter to result in a pure RF FSK emission (which is quite different from the more complicated emission you get if your feed audio FSK into an AM or FM radio channel).

However, in the case where data is to be transmitted or further processing performed with specialized gear rather than a re-purposed voice link, it's more customary to input I & Q baseband signals in quadrature.  You'll probably find a lot of IQ input transmitter and IQ output receiver modules, though generally those intended to go in more complicated projects rather than the complete RF modules intended to be connected to external micros of the type you seem to have been looking at.

Answer (score 0):

nRF2460 will convert your signal to digital, apply GFSK modulation, transmit in bursts at 1Mb/sec, and demodulate at the other end. That may not be what you want.

The reason why modulation is always included along with the filters and IF mixers is that the modulation affects the spectral characteristics and bandwidth of the signal. The entire TX/RX path depends on the modulation design.

If you're doing digital encryption, it will be applied to the bits of the signal, and it's fine to just send that bitstream over eg. the Nordic 2401 modules.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the info about the nRF2460, I found that information on all their other products, i just couldnt find it on their audio streamers.

"The reason why modulation is always included along with the filters and IF mixers is that the modulation affects the spectral characteristics and bandwidth of the signal. The entire TX/RX path depends on the modulation design"  

I plan on QAM modulating the signal first taking that into account. I want to encrypt the QAM modulated signal and transmit it as is, without modulating it AGAIN. that should theoretically be possible.

Comment: What encryption are you applying and how, given that the QAM-modulated signal is inherently analog?

Comment: That quoted sentance from this answer is not really accurate in the general case.  Modulation is not always performed by an RF module, IQ input/output RF stages are fairly common particularly for this type of goal.

Answer (score -1):

So why don't You take a fast and simple DAC? I've even seen FM audio transmitter using VGA DAC, connecting antenna directly to VGA output red channel. Probably that video is still on YouTube.

Comment: It's just a bit more complicated than that - filtering is definitely required, power amplification may be desirable.

Comment: As for the useful part of your comment, software defined radio can be a major part of an answer, but it is inevitably constrained by the conversion and sampling process.  A major one of those constraints is needing to filter out the sampling and conversion artifacts after returning to the analog RF domain, so that you only emit meaningful energy in the frequency ranges where you are supposed to.